# Vue how to inject adsense script to head

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to include adsense on my website however i have to include this script to the head

```
<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXX" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

How can i programmatically inject the script to head?

> I could add it in index.html in `dist/` however i don't track `dist/` on my git
>
> It will bite me one day when i switch PC's

Comment: You would usually add it in `public/index.html` if you're using the default vue project layout

Comment: `Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js”.` after adding.
However google verified that they found the script...is that normal?

Comment: Maybe your adblocker / other browser extension blocked the request?